# How to create title when exporting to CSV in SSRS 2012

Tags: sql-server, csv, reporting-services

How can I render SSRS report in CSV format and keep the title (Report name, Date parameters etc).

The report in design mode looks like this:

[image]

If I render it in CSV, all header part becomes rows.

[image]

Is any way to keep the header (report name and parameter selections) separate from main data?

Something like that:

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible with a CSV export

Comment: Agree with @Harry, but would add that you could do this with SSIS using a script task, or with a .net application.   But not SSRS.